# What kind of caterpillar type bug is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I've made a photo using the reversed 58 mm lens and my cropped DSLR:

[image: Unknown caterpillar]

Could you please help? I really don't know where this came from.

I found it in Russia.

Comment: Cannot help you but maybe it could be useful if you specified where you found it (inside, outside, which country, when, etc.?)

Comment: I found it in my kitchen on a clean plate from IKEA :) Country is Russia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely to be a black carpet beetle larvae

[image]

http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn7436.html

For more facts try: http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn7436.html 
Don't worry though, they live everywhere!

Wikipedia has some info on the family of beetles that they belong to (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestidae). I don't think they really cause any harm, except in natural history museums where they tend to munch the collections of animals...although this can also be a good thing:

'They are used in taxidermy and by natural history museums to clean animal skeletons' [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vidtF.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vidtF.jpg) VanClay, Mary. "Bitten By the Bug". www.johnsonstring.com. Retrieved November 10, 2012.

Comment: Definitely Dermestidae, but [*Dermestes lardarius*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestes_lardarius) (Larder beetle), [*Attagenus pellio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attagenus_pellio) (Fur beetle) and [*Anthrenus museorum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthrenus_museorum) (Museum beetle) are all common and likely. They can all be pest, also outside of museums, on e.g. fabrics, fur etc., but most that you find inside you house come from the outside. It might be worth the effort to check your clothes, other fabrics, stuffed animals or other suitable substrates if you find many of them.