# What is the name of the critter depicted in the attached image?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I found a critter on my bathroom towel. It's really tiny. Maybe 2 milimetres? I placed it on an envelope for the photograph.

Can someone identify what it is?

[image: A critter I found on my bathroom towel.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug a bed bug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/25848/bug-identification-is-this-small-tubular-black-bug-a-bed-bug)

Comment: Related: [What kind of insect can this be?...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/79183), [Can anyone help confirm this tiny insect larvae?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/66709), [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/25848), 
[How to protect my mounted insect specimens...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50599), [Varied Carpet Beetle Larvae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/68523), [What small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54158), [What bug is this...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/78326)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the larva of a [carpet beetle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_carpet_beetle).

> Larvae feed on natural fibers and can damage carpets, furniture, clothing and insect collections.

[image]

<sup>"Anthrenus verbasci - larva side (aka)" by André Karwath aka Aka on Wikimedia</sup>

Related question: [What kind of caterpillar is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7626/what-kind-of-caterpillar-is-this), though I think that the larva photographed in that example is either of a different species or at a different time period within the larval stage.