# Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug a bed bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

So I found this tiny bug on my wall in the bedroom of my apartment. I estimate it is about 3mm long by 1mm wide.

[image: Unknown Bug]

[image: Close up unknown bug]

Is it a bed bug?

It does not seem to match any of the pictures I've seen online.

The apartment is very clean by most standards. The only other bug I've seen in here is the odd stink bug.

Northeast coast of USA.

Comment: Not a bed bug - some kind of carpet beetle larvae maybe (judging by the hairiness)

Comment: Related: [What kind of insect can this be? This appears to be just a shell after and insect went through a metamorphosis process](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/79184/16866)

Comment: Related: [What kind of insect can this be?...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/79183), [Can anyone help confirm this tiny insect larvae?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/66709), [How to protect my mounted insect specimens...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50599), [Varied Carpet Beetle Larvae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/68523), [What is the name of the critter depicted...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23305), 
[What small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54158), [What bug is this...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/78326)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to suggest it is the larvae of a carpet beetle. Initially I thought possibly the Varied carpet beetle because of the lighter patches near the posterior end similar to this picture from the wiki page on this species:

[image]

Having said that the geographical range might not be correct so it could be a similar species so I've dug a bit deeper. There are some 120 species in North America, from this [link](https://books.google.se/books?id=aWVi0IF_jcQC&pg=PA210&lpg=PA210&dq=carpet%20beetle%20species%20america&source=bl&ots=N11Rs5NL7D&sig=pVhd_eSpUfmy5ARXSpUX7md_fW8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f2KMVM3VO8jKO-PQgKgN&ved=0CFwQ6AEwDA#v=onepage&q=carpet%20beetle%20species%20america&f=false) I'd say that the Buffalo carpet beetle is a contender.

Carpet beetles are classified as a pest species:

> "larvae feed on natural fibers and can damage carpets, furniture, clothing and insect collections"

Not all bad though, the larvae are also known as *wooly bears*, how nice.

Comment: Well that's good news. Better than bed bugs. Phew! Thanks!

Comment: well, woolly bears more often refer to a species of tiger-moth caterpillar: [*Pyrrharctia isabella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrharctia_isabella)