# Is this woodlouse or bed bug?

Tags: species-identification

I have found 3 of these things in the main bedroom within 4 days of each other. A little freaked out, can someone advise if these are woodlouse or bed bugs? and now just added another pic (first pic?) which seems to be an entirely different bug? Carpet beetle? ...that I just found in a cupboard?

[image][image]I have found 3 of these things in the main bedroom within 4 days of each other. A little freaked out, can someone advise if these are woodlouse or bed bugs? [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome Jax. Which photo are you referring to? The reason I ask is that you seem to have 4 photos of 3 different creatures. Could you add that detail, bearing in mind we answer single focused questions one per post, and tell us whereabouts in the world you are.

Comment: Apologies, the top pic and creature was one I discovered this morning after I made my original post. I think the first pic is a carpet beetle? the 2nd pic, did wonder if that was a moth as it looks different, this was in a draw. Last two are the main ones that I was finding and my main concern as I found two on Friday and another last night. These are the ones that I am hoping are woodlouse and not bed bugs, but I am not sure?

Comment: To add, I'm in London, UK.  and sorry I didn't realise you are meant to have single focus questions. To be honest I thought pics 2-4 might be all the same, but your suggestion 3 different types made me question the one from the draw which I think could be a moth.

Answer (score 4):

The insect on the first image is a [ladybeetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coccinellidae), likely the [Asian ladybeetle (*Harmonia axyridis*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonia_axyridis), a species which is well-known to enter buildings, especially for overwintering.

The subsequent photos likely depict the [larvae of a carpet beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestidae) - compare to [this answer here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/25849/39466).

Comment: You say the subsequent pics show larvae beetle, but when I look at that link, it looks like the one from the first pic?  Can someone clarify what the bottom two pics are? i.e one on the wall and one of the grey fabric

Comment: @JaxConrad The bottom two are very likely carpet beetle larvae. Google "carpet beetle larvae" (without quotes) and click on the tag underneath, images.