# What small insect is this?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

Lately, lots of these little bugs have been lurking in my house in Italy. Should I worry?
[image]
I'm curious to know what they are.
For reference, the 2 cent Euro is 18.75 mm in diameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug a bed bug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/25848/bug-identification-is-this-small-tubular-black-bug-a-bed-bug)

Comment: Related: [What kind of insect can this be?...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/79183), [Can anyone help confirm this tiny insect larvae?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/66709), [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/25848), 
[How to protect my mounted insect...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50599), [What is the name of the critter depicted...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23305), [Varied Carpet Beetle Larvae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/68523), [What bug is this...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/78326)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a [carpet beetle larvae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_carpet_beetle#Identification)(Anthrenus verbasci) to me. This seems to fit considering you found it in your house, which is one place they are fairly common. I would not be able to tell you if you should be worried, I am not a biologist.