# Can anyone help confirm this tiny insect larvae?

Tags: species-identification

Can anyone help identify this insect larvae?

Found: UK, autumn, in a bed.

Size: less than 2mm

[image: Larvae picture]

[image: Picture 2]

The bed was searched thoroughly and no others were found, but is there likely to be more of them?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [What kind of insect can this be?...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/79183), [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug a bed bug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/25848), [How to protect my mounted insect specimens...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50599), [Varied Carpet Beetle Larvae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/68523), [What is the name of the critter depicted...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23305), [What small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54158), [What bug is this...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/78326)

Answer (score 6):

> Can anyone help identify this insect larvae?

This is a [varied carpet beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_carpet_beetle) larva, which belongs to the species *Anthrenus verbasci*.

[image]
*A. verbasci. larval form, left; matured beetle, right.*

> The bed was searched thoroughly and no others were found, but is there likely to be more of them?

It's difficult to say, though, generally, ~40 eggs are produced at a time, and they can remain in the larval stage for 8 months to almost two years.

At any rate, the [University of California Agriculture & Natural Resources](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn7436.html), and [this](https://bugspray.com/articles98/carpetbeetle.html#where-do-carpet-beetles-nest) website, both provide solid information about this insect, and outline measurements that can be taken to protect your home from it.

Comment: It's also called a buffalo beetle. This is the varied [or also called variegated] form; there are other forms like the black carpet beetle.