# Varied Carpet Beetle Larvae

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I keep finding what I'm 99% sure are carpet beetle larvae on my walls, of all places. Yet when I look around and search thoroughly, I cannot find any signs of an(y) adult Beetle(s). Why/how is this happening and if it's not a carpet beetle larvae, then what is it?

Comment: Maybe attach a photo of one to this question?  That would help with the second part.

Comment: The eggs of carpet beetles would be exceedingly small. What makes you so sure? Also, seeing eggs of an insect, but not finding the adults would not be unusual at all.

Comment: I saw dozens of carpet beetle larvae in an old home I live in for more than a decade but never did I once see the adults. It can happen. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/25848/16866) for a visual.

Comment: Related: [What kind of insect can this be?...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/79183), [Can anyone help confirm this tiny insect larvae?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/66709), [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/25848), 
[How to protect my mounted insects...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50599), [What is the name of the critter depicted...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23305), [What small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54158), [What bug is this...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/78326)