# What animal is this from the kitchen

Tags: species-identification, entomology

The following picture has been taken in August [image: inside a box in the kitchen] inside a box
I’m the kitchen in a city at the center of France. What animal is this? The real size is about the size of a grain of rice

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is a common question, but hard to find the answer if you don't about image searches e.g. [Google Lens](https://lens.google/) — please have a look at the [links posted in the comment by @theforestecologist here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/68523/varied-carpet-beetle-larvae).

Comment: Thank you! I just tried with Google lens that suggests this is a larva of Varied carpet beetle.

Comment: it is the larva of many possible skin beetles (carpet beetles) including, possibly, the varied carpet beetle.