# What bug is this? I found several in my flat and I have no idea

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

what kind of insect  is this? is it a moth larvea or a carpet bug?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Bio.SE! Take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about the site and earn yourself your first badge. Also, adding the time and location where you found the insect is fundamental for its recognition!

Comment: Size as well as location are almost always needed for identification.  A clear picture would also be useful.

Comment: Location is almost never needed for insects, because insects, especially larvae, cannot be identified except to family level, and most families are cosmopolitan.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug a bed bug?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/25848/bug-identification-is-this-small-tubular-black-bug-a-bed-bug)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of insect can this be? This appears to be just a shell after and insect went through a metamorphosis process](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/79183/what-kind-of-insect-can-this-be-this-appears-to-be-just-a-shell-after-and-insec)

Comment: Related: [What kind of insect can this be?...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/79183), [Can anyone help confirm this tiny insect larvae?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/66709), [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/25848), 
[How to protect my mounted insect...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50599), [What is the name of the critter...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23305), [Varied Carpet Beetle Larvae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/68523), [What small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54158)

Answer (score 1):

That is the larva of a carpet or skin beetle, family Dermestidae.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestidae
These eat dried flesh, skin, and other dried organic matter. They are the bane of entomologists because they eat insect collections. They are used by bone-collectors to clean skeletons, and are the last insects to arrive at a corpse.