# What kind of insect can this be? This appears to be just a shell after and insect went through a metamorphosis process

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

What kind of insect can this be? This appears to be just a shell after an insect went through a metamorphosis process.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Can anyone help confirm this tiny insect larvae?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/66709), [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/25848), [How to protect my mounted insect specimens...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50599), [Varied Carpet Beetle Larvae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/68523), [What is the name of the critter depicted...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23305), [What small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54158), [What bug is this...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/78326)

Answer (score 9):

It's a carpet beetle larvae (family Dermestidae). 
See [here](https://entomology.ca.uky.edu/ef601) fore more info.

Example:

[image]

<sup>*Anthrenus verbasci* from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_carpet_beetle)</sup>