# What is this very tiny (3mm) centipede-like insect?

Tags: species-identification

[image]

My kid found this little guy in his bedroom. It’s about 2-3mm long. Lots of legs, and white rings around its abdomen.

Any idea what it is?

Edit: Location in San Jose, CA.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions please edit your post to include the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this creature. The location can be an essential clue for identifications. ——— If possible clear, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would also be helpful. ——— Please take the time to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Related: [What kind of insect can this be?...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/79183), [Can anyone help confirm this tiny insect larvae?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/66709), [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/25848), 
[How to protect my mounted insects...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50599), [What is the name of the critter depicted...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23305), [What small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54158), [What bug is this...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/78326)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a dermestid larva. A beetle from the family Dermestidae https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dermestidae, common name, skin beetle. They eat dried skin, or flesh, and are generally the last insect to feed on a carcass. They are the bane of insect collectors, because they eat dried insects right off the pin.