# What is this very tiny insect that was in my bedsheets?

Tags: species-identification

[image]
[image]
[image]
I found it in my bedsheets. I'm in Bordeaux, France. It is 3mm long and is the only one that I found.

Should I be worried that there might be others? If so, what should I do?

Comment: Related: [Can anyone help confirm this tiny insect larvae?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/66709), [Bug Identification: Is this small tubular, black bug...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/25848), [How to protect my mounted insect specimens...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/50599), [Varied Carpet Beetle Larvae](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/68523), [What is the name of the critter depicted...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/23305), [What small insect is this?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/54158), [What bug is this...](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/78326)

Answer (score 2):

That is almost certainly the larva of a carpet beetle, likely the [Furniture Carpet Beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthrenus_flavipes) (*Anthrenus flavipes*). They are distinctively hairy and striped.

[image]

(image from wikimedia)

Carpet beetles are found world-wide and are a pest of homes, workplaces, museums, basically anywhere that textiles, paper, or foods are contained. They will happily eat wool, silk, fur, hair, bone and shell (e.g. tortoise shell, not sea-shell).

Getting rid of them is difficult - you need to clean out any areas where they can live, this includes all your clothes (hot tumble-dry for 1 h, or keep in sealed bags for 2+ months), any natural-fiber carpets, cupboards, furniture - literally anywhere dust can accumulate. Often easiest to get a pest-control expert in to deal with them.

Comment: Although for items that are small enough, keeping in the freezer overnight would be more than enough, no need to ruin your clothes. They do not cause as much damage (relative to their population density) as clothes moths in my experience.

Comment: @CaroZ True, freezer should work, but the internets are telling me at least 48h, and that dry-cleaning and ironing should also work.